# Erro com HikariPool-1 spring

Tags: java, mysql, angular, spring-boot

Estou com esse erro quando tento inicializar o meu projeto spring. Não consigo achar nada para que desse certo resolver isso.

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.6.RELEASE)

2020-04-29 15:00:31.760  INFO 9820 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.a.api.AlgamoneyApiApplication        : Starting AlgamoneyApiApplication on DESKTOP-9CM18AF with PID 9820 (C:\Users\Ademar Pedro\Documents\workspace\algamoney-api\target\classes started by Ademar Pedro in C:\Users\Ademar Pedro\Documents\workspace\algamoney-api)
2020-04-29 15:00:31.764  INFO 9820 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.a.api.AlgamoneyApiApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-04-29 15:00:31.832  INFO 9820 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\Ademar Pedro\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\2.3.2\jaxb-runtime-2.3.2.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/Ademar%20Pedro/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.2.jar,file:/C:/Users/Ademar%20Pedro/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/txw2-2.3.2.jar,file:/C:/Users/Ademar%20Pedro/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.8.jar,file:/C:/Users/Ademar%20Pedro/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/stax-ex-1.8.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/Ademar%20Pedro/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/FastInfoset-1.2.16.jar,file:/C:/Users/Ademar%20Pedro/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.2/jakarta.activation-api-1.2.1.jar
2020-04-29 15:00:31.832  INFO 9820 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2020-04-29 15:00:31.832  INFO 9820 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2020-04-29 15:00:32.842  INFO 9820 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-04-29 15:00:32.869  INFO 9820 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 14ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-04-29 15:00:33.638  INFO 9820 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2020-04-29 15:00:33.649  INFO 9820 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-04-29 15:00:33.649  INFO 9820 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.33]
2020-04-29 15:00:33.757  INFO 9820 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-04-29 15:00:33.758  INFO 9820 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1925 ms
2020-04-29 15:00:33.919  INFO 9820 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-04-29 15:00:35.185 ERROR 9820 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
```

Meu properties

```
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/algamonyApi?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Ademar123

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Comment: Você realmente precisa do `Hikari-CP` neste momento?

Comment: Olá! Compartilhe o código do seu `pom.xml` na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Eu não coloquei o Hikari-CP, quando inicializei o projeto veio esse erro.

Arquivo pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.algaworks.algamoney-api</groupId>
    <artifactId>algamoney-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>algamoney-api</name>
    <description>algamoney-api</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```